# Connection coefficients and the metric tensor determinant relationship

Tags: general-relativity, metric-tensor, tensor-calculus

In my lecture notes we are presented with the relationship 
$$g^{ab}\partial_c g_{ab} = g^{-1} \partial_c g.$$ 
Where $g$ (no super/subscripts) indicates the determinant.

This is said to be a natural consequence of Jacobi's identity

$$(\det\mathbf{M^{-1}} \partial _c\det\mathbf{M}) = Tr(\mathbf{M^{-1}} \partial _c\mathbf{M}).$$

Can anybody explain this? I can't see how this applies, and specifically one point I don't get is how to take the trace of a tensor such as

$$g^{ij}\partial_c g_{kl}.$$

Comment: The last line should be $g^{ij}\partial_c g_{jk}$: that's the product of the two matrices. So the free indices are $i$ and $k$. To take the trace, you contract on those two.

Comment: @NickD Why is c not considered a free index?

Comment: Not sure what c is, but since it occurs in the matrix equation (where no indices occur at all), I took it to be a label on the derivative.

Answer (score 1):

The formula for general $M$ is a form of Jacobi's formula, and it's proved in math and physics textbooks. Now plug in
$$M_{ab} = g_{ab}$$
such that $\text{det}(M) = g$ and $M^{-1}_{ab} = g^{ab}$. The LHS of your formula gives
$$g^{-1} \partial_c \, g$$
and the RHS gives
$$\text{Tr}(g^{-1} \partial_c\, g) = g^{ab} \partial_c \, g_{ba}.$$
where now $g,g^{-1}$ mean matrices, not determinants.
(This is nothing but writing $\text{Tr}(AB) = A_{ij} B_{ji}$ with $A = g^{-1}$ and $B = \partial_c g$.)

Comment: Could you explain how we arrive at the following relathionship too please (I've seen it's an application of the chain rule but I' not quite sure I get how)

$$\frac{1}{2}g^{-1}\partial_c g = g^{-1/2}\partial_c g^{1/2}$$

Comment: Nevermind, I can see that via the chain rule

$$g^{-1/2}\partial_c g^{1/2} = \frac{1}{2} g^{-1/2}g^{-1/2} \partial_c g^{1/2} = \frac{1}{2}g^{-1}\partial_c g$$